# react-native android metro was not connecting

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, metro-bundler

I have created multiple variants in android build.gradle, while running android in react-native the app is running smoothly.But, the metro was not connecting to the running app.In ios it is working fine,metro is connecting properly.

how to connect metro to android while running android app in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

To connect Metro to an Android device while running an app in React Native, you can follow these steps:

1. Make sure that your Android device is connected to the same network as your development machine.
2. Open a terminal in your React Native project folder.
3. Start Metro bundler by running the following command:

   ```
   npx react-native start
   ```

   This will start the Metro bundler on your development machine.
4. In the same terminal, compile and run your Android app by running the following command:

   ```
   npx react-native run-android
   ```

   This will compile the app and install it on the connected Android device.
5. Once the app is installed and running on the Android device, you should see some logs in the terminal.
6. Verify that Metro is connecting to the running app by checking the logs in the terminal. You should see output similar to the following:

   ```
   Starting React Native packager...
   ...
   Metro Bundler ready.
   ...
   Loading dependency graph, done.
   ```

   This indicates that Metro is connected and serving the JavaScript bundle to the Android app.

If Metro is still not connecting to the Android app, you can try the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure that your device and development machine are connected to the same network without any firewall restrictions or proxies.
2. Check the development server URL setting in your Android app's `MainActivity.java` file. It should match the IP address and port of your development machine where Metro is running. For example:

   ```java
   protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
     return "index";
   }

   protected String getJSBundleFile() {
     return "http://YOUR_MACHINE_IP:8081/index.bundle?platform=android";
   }
   ```

   Replace `YOUR_MACHINE_IP` with the IP address of your development machine.
3. Ensure that you don't have any other instances of Metro running on your development machine that could be conflicting with the connection.

If the issue persists, you can provide more details about any error messages or logs you are seeing during the process, which will help in further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reverse the `tcp:8081`. On terminal type:

- `$ adb devices` This will give you an ID of the device that is connected or id of the emulator.
- `$ adb -s ADD_ID_HERE reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` replace ADD_ID_HERE with the id you're running your app on and then run the app not from android studio.